# SECURITY WARNING:"Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am working on app that contains facebook login .After login with face book I need to go to native application & app should display user name & image that was there in face book .But when I am logining with facebook It is showing "SECURITY WARNING:"Please  treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. in ios" ,& not coming back to my native app .Can any one sort this issue.I am using Facebook Graph api for face book.

In AppDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{ 
  return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation { 
  return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Comment: Why so many questions with all CAPS today? Did you handle custom URL in your AppDelegate, as taught in the getting start documentation of Facebook iOS SDK ?

Comment: -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{
    return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[_viewController facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
} this I written in appdelegate class I am getting Id but I am unable to come back  to native application

Comment: helped you add codes to question. Did you set the App ID in the app's `.plist` as well?

Comment: I created app & added appid   FB_Graph = [[FbGraph alloc]initWithFbClientID:APPID];

Comment: please help any one to sort out this issue I am new to ios why error is coming how to solve this can any one explain this please

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with my ios app and this is what i have done to resolve my problem. i have found the below url in my app and changed the connection from http to https.

earlier url: http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

changed url: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html

now it's working fine.

Comment: nothing happened same error that link is in the login method right?

Comment: Same massage for me too. Nothing happen. Can you please check it again

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. I hope it will work for you.

Just paste this UIWebViewDelegate method in your FbGraph.m file....

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([request.URL.relativeString hasPrefix:@"https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" ])
        self.webView.hidden=TRUE;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved per Zack24 on Apr 24.

Here is my webView loadRequest URL. Note the https for the redirect_uri.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=147261088671924&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&display=touch&type=user_agent&scope=read_stream,publish_stream

Answer (score -1):

Apart from implementing :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`
```

you have to add `URL Types > URL Schemes` into your application plist, with value : `fb1234567890` where `1234567890` is your App ID.

See Item 5: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

Comment: when i was downloading facebook sdk it is showing an error "error in downloading face book sdk"I have downloaded 5 times it is showing same error .please provide me any sample application that works correctly.Kindly any one sort this issue please