# Facebook GraphApi stuck in login success page

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have integrated facebook graph api is several applications but recently I have encountered a problem, while I have `Secure Browsing` **enabled** in my **Facebook Profile** -> **Privacy Settings** -> **Security**, and using simple `FBGraphApi` it passes all the steps of asking permissions and all but stucks on last step that is it doesn't get `accesstoken` in the redirect url set to `http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` where as as soon as I disable the `Secure Browsing` the login goes fine, and I get the `accesstoken` appended in the `redirect uri`.

The problem is Yes I am able to make it work, but it is impossible to tell all users to disable the `Secure Browsing` from their profile, and it won't bea good thing to do too..

Please give some thoughts on this, if any one encountered similar problem..

My problem is similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105113/something-wrong-with-facebook-it-gives-security-warning-please-treat-the-url-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with our application. A co-worker did some research and found that if you started the request process (oauth dialog in our case) using `https://` instead of `http://` then it would work with or without secure browsing enabled.

So

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=page...
```

turned into

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?response_type=token&display=page...
```

**EDIT**

There was also a redirect URL in the URL(s) above which he also changed to `https`