# URL issue in Facebook in BlackBerry

Tags: facebook, blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I have integrated Facebook in my app and trying to share some content.When I call FaceBookMain() ,it shows error like :
"**Success
SECURITY WARNINNG:Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.**"
Sometimes this error comes after login with Facebook in browser(Webview) otherwise it comes just after clicking on share button.

Most important thing here is ,I am not facing this problem in simulator.Sharing with Facebook is working properly in Simulator but not in Device.

I am adding some class files with it:

Here is FacebookMain.java class:

```
import net.rim.device.api.applicationcontrol.ApplicationPermissions;
import net.rim.device.api.applicationcontrol.ApplicationPermissionsManager;
import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentObject;
import net.rim.device.api.system.PersistentStore;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;

public class FacebookMain implements ActionListener{// extends MainScreen implements ActionListener {

    // Constants

    public final static String NEXT_URL = "http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
    public final static String APPLICATION_ID = "406758776102494";//"533918076671162" ;
    private final static long persistentObjectId = 0x854d1b7fa43e3577L;

    static final String ACTION_ENTER = "updateStatus";
    static final String ACTION_SUCCESS = "statusUpdated";
    static final String ACTION_ERROR = "error";
    private ActionScreen actionScreen;

    private PersistentObject store;

    private LoginScreen loginScreen;
    private LogoutScreen logoutScreen;
    private HomeScreen homeScreen;
    private UpdateStatusScreen updateStatusScreen;
    private RecentUpdatesScreen recentUpdatesScreen;
    private UploadPhotoScreen uploadPhotoScreen;
    private FriendsListScreen friendsListScreen;
    private PokeFriendScreen pokeFriendScreen;
    private PostWallScreen postWallScreen;
    private SendMessageScreen sendMessageScreen;

    private String postMessage;

    private FacebookContext fbc;
    public static boolean isWallPosted=false;
    public static boolean isFacebookScreen = false;

    public FacebookMain(String postMessge) {
        this.postMessage= postMessge;
        isFacebookScreen = true;

        checkPermissions();

        fbc=new FacebookContext(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID);
        loginScreen = new LoginScreen(fbc,"KingdomConnect: "+postMessge);
        loginScreen.addActionListener(this);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(loginScreen);

    }

    private void init() {
        store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(persistentObjectId);
        synchronized (store) {
            if (store.getContents() == null) {
                store.setContents(new FacebookContext(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID));
                store.commit();
            }
        }
        fbc = (FacebookContext) store.getContents();
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {

        ApplicationPermissionsManager apm = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance();
        ApplicationPermissions original = apm.getApplicationPermissions();

        if ((original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) && (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DEVICE_SETTINGS) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) && (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_CROSS_APPLICATION_COMMUNICATION) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) && (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) && (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW) && (original.getPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_EMAIL) == ApplicationPermissions.VALUE_ALLOW)) {
            return;
        }

        /*ApplicationPermissions permRequest = new ApplicationPermissions();
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DEVICE_SETTINGS);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_CROSS_APPLICATION_COMMUNICATION);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_EMAIL);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_AUTHENTICATOR_API);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_WIFI);*/
        ApplicationPermissions permRequest = new ApplicationPermissions();
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INPUT_SIMULATION);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_DEVICE_SETTINGS);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_CROSS_APPLICATION_COMMUNICATION);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK);
        permRequest.addPermission(ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_EMAIL);

        boolean acceptance = ApplicationPermissionsManager.getInstance().invokePermissionsRequest(permRequest);

        if (acceptance) {
            // User has accepted all of the permissions.
            return;
        } else {
        }
    }

    public void saveContext(FacebookContext pfbc) {
        synchronized (store) {
            store.setContents(pfbc);
            System.out.println(pfbc);
            store.commit();
        }
    }

    public void logoutAndExit() {
        saveContext(null);
        logoutScreen = new LogoutScreen(fbc);
        logoutScreen.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void saveAndExit() {
        saveContext(fbc);
        exit();
    }

    private void exit() {
        AppenderFactory.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void onAction(Action event) {}
}
```

It is Facebook.java class:

```
   public class Facebook {

        protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
        public static String API_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com";

        public Facebook() {
        }

        public static Object read(String path, String accessToken) throws FacebookException {
            return read(path, null, accessToken);
        }

        public static Object read(String path, Parameters params, String accessToken) throws FacebookException {
            Hashtable args = new Hashtable();
            args.put("access_token", accessToken);
            args.put("format", "JSON");

            if ((params != null) && (params.getCount() > 0)) {
                Enumeration paramNamesEnum = params.getParameterNames();

                while (paramNamesEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String paramName = (String) paramNamesEnum.nextElement();
                    String paramValue = params.get(paramName).getValue();
                    args.put(paramName, paramValue);
                }
            }

            try {
                StringBuffer responseBuffer = HttpClient.getInstance().doGet(API_URL + '/' + path, args);

                if (responseBuffer.length() == 0) {
                    throw new Exception("Empty response");
                }

                return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(responseBuffer.toString()));

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                throw new FacebookException(t.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static Object write(String path, Object object, String accessToken) throws FacebookException {
            Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
            data.put("access_token", accessToken);
            data.put("format", "JSON");

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
                Enumeration keysEnum = jsonObject.keys();

                while (keysEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = (String) keysEnum.nextElement();
                    Object val = jsonObject.get(key);

                    if (!(val instanceof JSONObject)) {
                        data.put(key, val.toString());
                    }
                }

                StringBuffer responseBuffer = HttpClient.getInstance().doPost(API_URL + '/' + path, data);

                if (responseBuffer.length() == 0) {
                    throw new FacebookException("Empty response");
                }

                return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(responseBuffer.toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FacebookException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static Object delete(String path, String accessToken) throws FacebookException {
            Hashtable data = new Hashtable();
            data.put("access_token", accessToken);
            data.put("format", "JSON");
            data.put("method", "delete");

            try {
                StringBuffer responseBuffer = HttpClient.getInstance().doPost(API_URL + '/' + path, data);

                if (responseBuffer.length() == 0) {
                    throw new FacebookException("Empty response");
                }

                return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(responseBuffer.toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new FacebookException(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }


And it is BrowserScreen.class:

public class BrowserScreen extends ActionScreen {

    //  int[] preferredTransportTypes = { TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B };
    int[] preferredTransportTypes = TransportInfo.getAvailableTransportTypes();//{ TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B };
    ConnectionFactory cf;
    BrowserFieldConfig bfc;
    BrowserField bf;
    String url;

    public BrowserScreen(String pUrl) {
        super();
        url = pUrl;

        cf = new ConnectionFactory();
        cf.setPreferredTransportTypes(preferredTransportTypes);

        bfc = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR, Boolean.TRUE);
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_SCALABLE, Boolean.TRUE);
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.MDS_TRANSCODING_ENABLED, Boolean.FALSE);
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, new Integer(Display.getWidth()));
        //      bfc.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.CONNECTION_FACTORY, cf);

        bf = new BrowserField(bfc);

    }

    public void browse() {
        show();
        fetch();
    }

    public void show() {
        add(bf);
    }

    public void fetch() {
        bf.requestContent(url);
    }

    public void hide() {
        delete(bf);
    }

}
```

If any body has any clue or want some more related code to get it,please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

do not use secure connection. **use http** instead of https.

you can refer  [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/qs7CfaqTgpU)

same problem is presented in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033462/security-warningplease-treat-the-url-above-as-you-would-your-password-and-do-n)

facebook [warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141440/facebook-security-warning-while-user-has-enabled-secure-login-iphone/16831606#16831606)